# Required String parameter 'username' is not present when trying to set session attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, attributes, httpsession

I'm trying to set username as Http session attribute when user loging in but it gives me an error

> Required String parameter 'username' is not present

This is my controller class, getLoginForm method. Here I'm trying to get username string from input and puting it to httpSession (because i will need this username to use in other requests).

```
package com.vandh.app.controller;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("username")
public class LoginController {


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" })
    public String getUserDefault() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView getLoginForm(@ModelAttribute Users users,
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
            @RequestParam(value="username") String username,
            HttpSession httpSession) {

        String message = "";
        if (error != null) {
            message = "Incorrect username or password !";
        } else if (logout != null) {
            message = "Logout successful !";
        }
        else
            if(error==null)
            {
                httpSession.setAttribute("username", username);
            }
        return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin**")
    public String getAdminProfile() {
        return "admin";
    }



    @RequestMapping("/403")
    public ModelAndView getAccessDenied() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        String username = "";
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
            username = userDetail.getUsername();
        }

        return new ModelAndView("403", "username", username);
    }
}
```

Here is my DAO class of finding users in DB (MySQL)

```
@Repository("loginDao")
public class LoginDaoImpl implements LoginDao {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    //public String userLogIn; // checking username in auth. process
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    @Override
    public Users findByUserName(String username ) {
        String login = username;
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Users user = (Users) session.load(Users.class, new String(username));
        tx.commit();
        return user;

    }
}
```

And this is my login.jsp page

```
  <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login </title>
</head>
<body>

        <br /> <br /> <br />
        <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; padding-top: 10px;">
            <br /> Please enter your username and password to login ! <br /> <span
                style="color: red">${message}</span> <br />
            <form:form method="post" action="j_spring_security_check"
                modelAttribute="users">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:</td>
                        <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><form:input path="password" type="password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you change from this to <form:input path="username" /> to can you change from this to <form:input name="username" /> ?

Comment: @vishalgajera, thanx for an answer but nothing changed

Comment: make it correct like <form:input type="text" name="username" /> if not work then replace 'username' by 'j_username', If i am not wrong then it's part of spring-security. please do this changes. let's see any luck ?

Comment: @vishalgajera thanx, but nothing changed ((